# Handle HTTP response's headers

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

My API manages pagination via headers and I try to handle these in angular.

If I use chrome console I can find headers :

[image]

My responses handling method :

```
  /**
   * Get the body of an HTTP response.
   *
   * @param res
   * @returns {any|{}}
   */
  private static handleBody(res: Response) {
    console.log(res.headers);
    return res.json() || {};
  }
```

the result is :

[image]

How can I get my pagination headers in my angular app ?

Comment: Isn't the pagination usually defined as a parameter in the request?`api/somerequest?page=x`

Comment: For the request (GET /users?page=1&size=10) but response's pagination is in headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your browser is trying to protect you by not exposing custom headers.

You can permit headers by adding an additional response [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers):

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Page, X-Per-Page, X-Total, X-Total-Pages
```

You should then be able to access these in the response.

WIthout this, you may only be able to access the simple headers:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

Comment: I added `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` into my server and it works perfectly. Thanks.